# Starting a new activity from a surfaceview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Trying to start a new activity from my class GameView.class that extends SurfaceView.
With this (found it here on Stackoverflow):

```
Context context = GameView.this.getContext();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ScoreScreen.class));
```

I put it in a method that gets called from a separate thread.
When it gets triggered the app just freezes. I tried putting it directly in the onTouch event (to skip the whole game and test it quicker) and it crashes all together with:

```
11-27 08:00:00.430: W/dalvikvm(1772): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e7b300)
11-27 08:00:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1772): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-598
11-27 08:00:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1772): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 08:00:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1772):     at com.tricky.puzzlepoker.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:173)
11-27 08:00:00.430: E/AndroidRuntime(1772):     at com.tricky.puzzlepoker.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:38)
11-27 08:00:02.505: I/Process(1772): Sending signal. PID: 1772 SIG: 9
```

I have no idea what to do anymore, need help!

Comment: I think GameView is null (might be something else). Find out what's null and why. Preferably by debugging.

Comment: what is on line 173 of GameView class ?

Comment: Context context = getContext();  
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScoreScreen.class);  
context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: There is no onCreate in the SurfaceView class. But for generating the SurfaceClass view you have to pass the context with its constructor. so you should store the context directly in the constructor to a global variable. Then you can use this context later for starting your activity... this should work..

Comment: I think we need more code to find the issue

Comment: thanks a million cianci! It worked! I think i need to read up a little though, in to deep, i still dont understand context. Any good reading tips?? (ps. i voted your answer up, but i dont know how i can mark it as being the answer)

Comment: ok weird thing, i tried it in the onTouchEvent and it worked. But when i put it in my own gameUpdate() method it freezes again.

Comment: I need some more code regarding this. What do you do exactly in the gameUpdate() method? Have you stored the context before, eg. in the constructor? regarding good reading tips i always try to use the google guidelines http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html and then practice :)

Comment: i wrote an answer so you can accept it as answer if you like. i think comments cant be marked as answers.

Answer (score 2):

The SurfaceView class extends from View and has no onCreate() method. But the constructor needs a context which you have to overgive when creating the GameView object. So I would suggest you store the context to a global variable for later use in this class:

```
   private class GameView extends SurfaceView {
     private Context mContext;
     ...
     public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       this.mContext = context;
       ...
     }
     ...
    }
```

Otherwise you can get the context everywhere else in the GameView class with:

```
    mContext = getContext();
```

With this context you can start later your activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ScoreScreen.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```